# Extract data from web page in a job Talend/ Configure a job talend from UI using java

Tags: java, url, talend, jobs, configure

I am new in Talend and just discovering multiple advantages of its components so I can begin my project.

For this aim I want to know if there is a possibility to upload data from web page using talend job? from this page for example https://www.bloomberg.com/middleeast Iknow that this functionality exists in power BI but can't find it in Talend.

Also I am willing to call the job from a java code under a control on a button on user interface, can someone tell me if there is possibility to configure the job from the user interface? It means to choose for example the input and output of a job from a UI?

Yous answers will help me a lot thank you very much in advance Smiley Very Happy

Comment: Hello echtouka and welcome to Talend ! Can you post the second part of your question (passing configuration parameters to the job) in a separate question please ? It allows each question to be more focused.

Comment: Hello carasus, thanks for the advice.

Comment: Sooooo .... Could you separate your posts ?